# Reputation to comment

Tags: discussion

How do I gain 50 reputations to comment when I have no way of gaining any reputation at all because the screen where I'm to comment says I need 50 reputations.

PS Your site is most confusing to a tyro.

Comment: Here is a [link explaining how to earn "reputation"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) it's not that difficult. You can start by editing posts, if they are approved you earn 2 rep. If you post an answer to any question and it gets upvoted you earn 10 rep, etc.